# How to save the function random number inside a variable

Tags: javascript

I want to do something like this:

```
var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1);
    console.log("What is the answer of: " + randomNum + " + " + randomNum + "?");
    console.log("What is the answer of: " + randomNum + " + " + randomNum + "?");
    console.log("What is the answer of: " + randomNum + " + " + randomNum + "?");
    console.log("What is the answer of: " + randomNum + " + " + randomNum + "?");
```

and inside the console I want it to get:
What is the answer of: 5 + 6? 
when we refresh the page we should get another number for example:
What is the answer of: 3 + 1? 
etc..
normal random function but with assigning it to a variable;
because when I do that it just keep printing the same number?
insde my console:
What is the answer of: 1 + 1?
second refresh
What is the answer of: 3 + 3?
third refresh:
What is the answer of: 2 + 2?
and so on, **The both cells has the same value?** 
I can fix it without DRY (don't repeat your self) by the basic structure:

```
//var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1);
console.log("What is the answer of: " + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1) + " + " + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1) + "?");
```

But as you know maybe I'm doing a big project so I should not repeat my self, right?

Comment: Make it a function that you keep calling: `console.log('...' + rand() + '...' + rand())`.

Comment: May I know why I got down vote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do it like this: `var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1);`, first the right side of the expression is evaluated, then assigned into randomNum. So ofc it will stay the same.

just turn it into a function:

`randomNum = () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1);`

Answer (score 0):

This will work, you need to make it a function

```
var randomNum = () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1);
```

then you can use it as `randomNum()`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a function that creates 2 unique random numbers and call it upon `DOMContentLoaded` event being fired:

```js
//Call your random number function when DOM is fully loaded and parsed
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init)

function init() {
  //We have to create 2 unique random numbers here (not just one):
  const a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1),
    b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1);

  console.log(`${a} + ${b} = ${a + b}`);
}
```